# How do you find out someones soundcloud userid?

Tags: soundcloud

I've literally looked everywhere and cannot figure out how to find someones userid that I can use inside their embed code. Anyone know how to find it out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out `What is my SoundCloud user_id?` from `timpietrusky`:

http://timpietrusky.github.io/what-is-my-soundcloud-user-id/

If you want the user id of another user, you need to have their permalink (containing the username). Then you can use the /resolve endpoint from the API to get their data, including the id

Learn more on [/resolve in the documentation](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#resolve)

Answer (score 12):

Simply take a look into the source head section.

```
<meta property="twitter:app:url:googleplay" content="soundcloud://users:IDHERE">
<meta property="twitter:app:url:iphone" content="soundcloud://users:IDHERE">
<meta property="twitter:app:url:ipad" content="soundcloud://users:IDHERE">
<meta property="twitter:player" content="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Fusers%2FIDHERE&amp;auto_play=false&amp;show_artwork=true&amp;visual=true&amp;origin=twitter">
```

and several other meta tags ...

Answer (score 11):

Tim's project seems to be broken. Figured I'd just copy and paste the solution here. Thanks subZero!

```
curl -v 'http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=http://soundcloud.com/YOUR_USER_NAME&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID'
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have the soundcloud user name and just need to find the id (i used it to get the RSS feed for another user): Go to the soundcloud page (eg: https://soundcloud.com/50_cent), right click and view source, look for the id (eg: soundcloud://users:1548017). That's your user id: 548017

Comment: you can find it in the meta tags on once you 'view source' , just do a search for "users" and you will see it pop up multiple times

Answer (score 2):

Update:

First of all, use documentation [Reference /resolve](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#resolve) for up to date solution.

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve?url=http://soundcloud.com/USER_NAME&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID
```

Replace USER_NAME with user name from regular SoundCloud link like `https://soundcloud.com/USER_NAME`, and you app's client ID.
Note, there is no `.json` in `/resolve` anymore.